# How to add/remove Vector Layer from a Map

Tags: openlayers

I have doubts about how to show or hide a vector layer on the map once I have created it. I generate it after doing a php query and receiving the data in json.
This is the function that I use to send the data to the query and once the json is received I paint it on the map:

```
function search(){
    var element = document.getElementById("formName");
    obje = document.getElementById('cbx_esp');
    var txt='';
    txt = "\""+obje.value+"\"";
    url_obje = 'abundance='+txt;
    drawAbundance(obje.value);
}
function drawAbundance(cbx_espId){
    var vectorAbundance = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new  ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
            var proj = projection.getCode();
            var url = "obAbundance.php"
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var params = {
                abundance: cbx_espId
            }

            xhr.open('POST', url);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            var onError = function() {
               vectorAbundance.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
            }
            xhr.onerror = onError;
            xhr.onload = function() {
                xhr.responseText;
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    vectorAbundance.addFeatures(
                        vectorAbundance.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText)
                    );
                    map.getView().fit(vectorAbundance.getExtent());
                    $("#formName")[0].reset();
               } else {
                 onError();
               }
             }
             xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        },
    });
    var vectorlayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source:vectorAbundance,
        visible:true,
        displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
        style: distICES,                
    });

    map.addLayer(vectorlayer)
}

//I tried this to show or not the veclayer
function add_de(e){
    if(e.checked){
        map.addLayer(vectorlayer);
    }else{
        map.removelayer(vectorlayer);
    }
}
```

I tried to create an input check and depending on whether it was checked or not, the vector layer was loaded, but it gives me the error that it is not defined:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: vectorlayer is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration `var vectorlayer` is within function `drawAbundance`. You second function can't access it because of scope. See this article https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-scope/#3-function-scope as your issue is not really related to OpenLayers but to JavaScript in fact.

A correction below just for this issue.

```
function search(){
    var element = document.getElementById("formName");
    obje = document.getElementById('cbx_esp');
    var txt='';
    txt = "\""+obje.value+"\"";
    url_obje = 'abundance='+txt;
    drawAbundance(obje.value);
}

var vectorlayer;

function drawAbundance(cbx_espId){
    var vectorAbundance = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new  ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
            var proj = projection.getCode();
            var url = "obAbundance.php"
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var params = {
                abundance: cbx_espId
            }

            xhr.open('POST', url);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            var onError = function() {
               vectorAbundance.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
            }
            xhr.onerror = onError;
            xhr.onload = function() {
                xhr.responseText;
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    vectorAbundance.addFeatures(
                        vectorAbundance.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText)
                    );
                    map.getView().fit(vectorAbundance.getExtent());
                    $("#formName")[0].reset();
               } else {
                 onError();
               }
             }
             xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        },
    });
    vectorlayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source:vectorAbundance,
        visible:true,
        displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
        style: distICES,                
    });

    map.addLayer(vectorlayer)
}

//I tried this to show or not the veclayer
function add_de(e){
    if(e.checked){
        map.addLayer(vectorlayer);
    }else{
        map.removelayer(vectorlayer);
    }
}
```

Comment: what you propose doesn't solve the problem @ThomasG77

Comment: The answer above definitely solves the problem you described in your question. Are you saying that you still get the same error? In that case you probably forgot to remove `var` part from `var vectorlayer = new ol.layer.Vector(...`.

Comment: It gave me an AssertionError because I previously added the veclayer in the drawAbunda function, and in the add_de function the first check was to load the layer that was already added to the map, it was only to change the order in the add_de function. Thank you very much @ ThomasG77 and @TomazicM